# On macOS Mojave, in a cocoa application, how to use AVSpeechSynthesizer?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, text-to-speech

[AVSpeechSynthesizer is marked as available on macOS Mojave beta.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizer)

Previously it was only available on iOS, tvOS and watchOS. But if I prepare a small macOS test project in Xcode 10, it gives me an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'AVSpeechSynthesizer'". on the top, I have:

```
import Cocoa
import NaturalLanguage
import AVFoundation
```

My code is:

```
let string = "Mickey mouse went to town"

let recognizer = NLLanguageRecognizer()
recognizer.processString(string)
let language = recognizer.dominantLanguage!.rawValue

let speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: string)
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: language)
speechSynthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

It is exactly the same code as on iOS, but on iOS it works, on macOS it gives the error. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently AVFAudio.h on Mojave has this:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#import <AVFAudio/AVAudioSession.h>
#import <AVFAudio/AVSpeechSynthesis.h>
#endif
```

And `AVSpeechSynthesizer` and friends are declared in AVSpeechSynthesis.h. This is the technical reason why you're seeing that error, those headers are only included when compiling for iOS.

But I've tried importing that header manually and I don't think `AVSpeechSynthesizer` is working correctly on Mojave even if that #if wasn't there. Trying to create an `AVSpeechUtterance` on Mojave always returns nil.

So this is either unfinished work on Mojave, or the headers are incorrectly annotated and speech synthesis is not available via AVFoundation on Mojave. Note that `NSSpeechSynthesizer` is still there and has not been marked deprecated.